# Contracting “des” into “de” in “je reviens de vacances”

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

*Je reviens des vacances.* and not 
*~je reviens de vacances.~*

I don't understand why *des* changes into *de* here. Is there a special case with the verb venir that leads to contracting the article following it and if so why is it correct to say “Je reviens de la mort” then?

I've come across several cases like this especially with verbs and it feels hard to memorise all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *des vacances* but when you are talking about a specific vacation:

> *Je reviens **des** vacances de février.*

If you don't, *vacances* is a generic, indefinite noun and doesn't take an article:

> *Je reviens **de** vacances.*

like we say:

> *Je rentre **de** vacances.
>
>   Je rentre **de** voyage.
>
>   J'ai besoin **de** vacances.
>
>   J'ai besoin **de** sucre.
>
>   J'ai besoin **de** sommeil.*

There is a difference between :

> *Je reviens **des** grandes vacances.* (I'm back from summer holidays)

and

> *Je reviens **de** grandes vacances.* (I'm back from long holidays)

This is actually a case of haplology (repeating sounds avoidance). The undefinite article (*des* or *du*) disappears when it follows the preposition *de*

What is intended to say is:

> *Je reviens "**de des**" vacances.*
>   *J'ai besoin "**de du**" sucre.*

*La mort* is not generic, it's not ***de de*** la mort: I'm back from (some) death, but ***de*** la mort: I'm back from (the) death, so you say:

> *Je reviens **de la** mort.*
>   *Je reviens **de la** prison.*: I'm returning from the jailhouse.

Other examples with *revenir*

> *Je reviens **d**'examens.* (**de des** examens)
>   *Je reviens **de** prison.* (**de de la** prison): I'm back from jail.

Reference: http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/060.html

Comment: @jiliagre but why Morte can't be generic after all we can specify Morte like : la morte de Nicolas,  la morte qui est dure. In addition, alot of the nouns you have mentioned above can take an article in another cases like : dans le sommeil , on fond le sucre. And there is that sentence also which I do not know why the article was omitted from : Ses murs sont ornés de photos.

Comment: Beware that the word is *mort* and not *morte* in your sentences. Both *mort* and *morte* are feminine...

Comment: Ahh I got it now. But just one last thing, why it is *je rentre de voyage* not *du voyage* or *d'un voyage*. I thought voyage is a definite noun.

Comment: I know it can mean *travelling* and when so it  takes *de* but when I search google for *du voyage* I find only *de voyage* .

Comment: If you are talking about a specific *voyage*, you say ***je reviens du voyage** inaugural de la nouvelle ligne de métro*. If you are talking about a unspecified *voyage*, but which has nevertheless some specificity, you say ***je reviens d'un voyage** en hélicoptère*.

Comment: Here is also another resource for french learners who may find the vocabs used in jiliagre's resource a bit difficult. http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/articles_leur_suppression.html

Answer (score 0):

> Je reviens de XXX

This is actually a very specific sentence that could translate to "I'm coming back from" : you can't really use another sentence to express the same.

- Je reviens de chez le voisin
- Je reviens de l'étranger
- Je reviens de magasins de mode
- etc.

Comment: Personnaly I have never heard "je reviens des vacances", but rather "je reviens de [mes] vacances". But then again, I'm not a fan of language rules, I'm just telling you on an everyday basis what I hear/say

Comment: You already heard ***Je reviens des vacances de Pâques***, didn't you?

Comment: Indeed I heard !